# Run a bash script to shutdown tomcat from another directory

Tags: linux, bash, tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I have two scripts, one to run the application shutdown for Tomcat server, and another that calls it when deploying.  So basically after Jenkins builds my application, and moves the deploy-able artifact to the server (linux).  Once that completes Jenkins kicks off a script to do the deployment of the application on Tomcat.  That deployment script calls another script to shutdown the currently running application on tomcat.  The problem I'm having is that it doesn't recognize anything is running on Tomcat.  So I end up with two instances of the application running at the same time on the server...and I get out of memory exceptions.  So this is the strange part.  If I try to run the script as `sudo /path/to/my/script stop` it doesn't recognize any application running on tomcat, but if I cd to the directory like `cd /path/to/my` and then run `sudo ./script stop` it works.  Does anyone know what the issue is?  I don't think this has to do with permissions, I am using the same user to do everything, build and deploy.  All files are owned by the same user, and I'm using `sudo` before the command.  Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: why `sudo` ? what's in `script` ?

Comment: I don't need sudo from inside the script.  I use that when I am typing this manually in the shell.  So the application is running as a different user than my user.  The shutdown script is an auto generated script built by hybris.  Again, I don't understand why this would work only if I navigate to the directory the script is in and not from outside the directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing what `script` does, this is the best you can do

```
(cd path/to/my && sudo ./script stop)
```

you can create an `alias` or a `function` if you like.

Answer (score 0):

What you actually want is to run hybris as a service and then start/stop this service.

On unix I will go with [systemd](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd) and System CTL.